# Vertical CSS Menu with borders inside links thats fills entire width

Tags: html, css, menu

For a website I need to make a css/html menu like this:

[image]

As you can see there some yellow borders to the left and also to the right of the menu links that fill up the availabe width. Also there is a background image underneath the menu with a gradient in it.

Does somebody has any idee on how to achive this menu style?

Code so far:

```
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="#">Wirtschaft<div></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Kurzeinführung Wirtschaft</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wirtschaftstheorie</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Arbeitsmarkt</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a href="/test.html">Geld- und Konjunktur</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Staatsfinanzen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wirtschaft: alle Beiträge</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#submenu {
    width: 225px;
}

#submenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#submenu ul li a {
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    padding-left: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    color: #222624;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#submenu ul li a:hover,
#submenu ul li.selected > a {
    border-left: 6px solid #CAB106;
}

#submenu ul li ul li a {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

EDIT: the gradient in the picture actually resides in the body and i think it can not be done with pure css so it has to be a background image.

EDIT2: the solution provided by PeterVR works great! unfortunately i am stuck with another list with the same style but without the blocks ending complete when the ul ends. any idea on how to achive this with the code provided by PeterVR?

[image: NewProb]

Comment: Since it's a vertical gradient, you could easily set the background image of the text to be a yellow block->menu text with gradient snippet behind->then another yellow block. You would not be able to achieve this if the gradient was horizontal so you are in luck

Comment: @Justin i have updated the basic code in my post. what i have tried is putting a div inside each anchor tag. but it doesn't real worked out. also tried to use a background image for simualting the yellow border. no success so far...

Comment: @Tim Joyce sorry, but gradient is actually not linear like in the picture above its a no standard radiant gradient residing in the body as a background image :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/AXze7/1/
I changed a few thing in your css:
 - set the main `ul` to overflow hidden
 - removed the display block from your `<a>` tags
 - set the `<a>` tags to position relative, for the following to work:

```
#submenu ul li a:hover:after,
#submenu ul li.selected > a:after {
    background: #CAB106;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 225px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

This adds the green blocks after the anchor tags.

EDIT:
I updated my fiddle for your second case: http://jsfiddle.net/AXze7/2/

A short overview of what changed:

- I removed the `overflow:hidden` from the `ul`, and put it on the `li`
- I tweaked the styling and played with the pixels to make it look a bit more like your screenshot. Comparing this with the previous example should help you understand how to achieve what.
- I added an extra pseudo-class `:before` for the arrow icon that appears to change on hover/select.

The code looks like this:

```
#submenu ul li a:before,
#submenu ul li.selected > a:before {
    background: #fcc; /* put your black arrow image here */
    content: ' '; 
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -18px;
    top: 2px;
}
#submenu ul li a:hover:before,
#submenu ul li.selected > a:before {
    background: red; /* put your colored arraw image here */
}
```

Comment: wow, very nice and elegant! thank you a lot, this is the solution! i even can adjust the height of the yellow (green?) blocks cause the blocks in the inner ul are not the same height as the text. again thank you!!!

Comment: @PeterVR any idea on how to achive second menu style, see edited post above a long with new screenshot.

Comment: @RexDude I updated my answer. Next time I will start charging you ;-)

Comment: @PeterVR thank you so much for your help!!! i am already feeling bad cause i get your support for free... :( unfortunately i have still the same problem: the blocks overlap the icon images cause they go on till end of ul/li's. my 2nd screenshot is not how it should be, but how it looks right now in my css/html. how is it possible to not have the blocks go on full width to the right so that they stop before the icons?

Comment: @RexDude no worries, i was just kidding. Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/AXze7/3/ Note that the hover icons already appear when the link is not yet clickable, which is not ideal in terms of ux. You could solve that by adding another span...

Comment: @PeterVR wow, you are amazing. again its working perfectly! thank you so much! you saved my day. i would have needed a long time to come up with such a nice solution. i think you are a css magician :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYx2P/2/)  in js fiddle.make an image one pixel height with the grenadine shown on the picture , and replace `#eee` with that image.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick answer. i updated my post cause unfortunately the gradient resides in the body and is not for the menu only. also second yellow border is not the same height as the text!